# Disable Whatsapp group notifications except from one person in that group

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

I want to turn off all sorts of group notifications from a specific group in Whatsapp, except if a specific person in that group sends a message there. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: AFAIK, it's impossible to do that, at least not from WhatsApp directly since it only provides a custom notification for the whole group, or mutes the notification for all messages, but no in-between/more sophisticated notification customization.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.